# Detecting nested arrays with is_array()

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

Right now I have the following array:

```
    $test = array(
      'allow' => array(
          'access_level' => array(
             'manager',
             'admin',
          ),
      ),
   ),
```

I’m doing a `foreach` loop on it:

```
foreach($test['allow'] as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($key)){
       echo "Its an array within an array!";
    }
}
```

But the key is never an array. How could I figure out if `access_level` is an array or just points to one value?

Comment: You accidentally are checking if 'allow' is an array instead of the array. 'allow' is the key, the array is `$value`

Comment: Yup, rookie mistake. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: if you don't need key, Don't fu*king define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `key` is the index of the element, and not the element's value.
You should test the `is_array()` against the `$value` (which is the current element in the loop) Like this:

```
is_array($value)
```

Or, against the array element that matches the `$key`, like this:

```
is_array($test['allow'][$key])
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `is_array($key)` to `is_array($value)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
if(is_array($value)){
       // echo ...
 }
```

Or :

```
if(is_array($test['allow'][$key])){
      // echo ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($test['allow'] as $key => $value) {
                                  ^ mind the dollar sign here
    if(is_array($value)){
       echo "Its an array within an array!";
    }
}
```

You should check against `$value`, not `$key`.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is `access_level` and `access_level` has a value of

```
array(
             'manager',
             'admin',
          ),
```

Check if the value is an array, not the key.

Its impossible in php for the key to an array to be an array